# How to run PHP with Nginx on Windows 10 bash WSL?

Tags: windows-10, bash, php

I have installed PHP7 and Nginx on Windows 10 bash.

PHP is installed at /etc/php/7.1
Nginx installed at /etc/nginx

I get 502 Bad Gateway when I try to go to localhost and load index.php

How can I configure /etc/nginx/sites-available/default so that it runs PHP scripts properly? So far, nothing I have tried works.

Comment: So what have you actually tried? Did you check the log files? What does your current configuration look like?

Comment: I tried to uncomment the section related to PHP in the configuration nginx file but that did not work. Thanks for idea for checking log files. Will do that next.

Comment: Did you adjust it to match your configuration? Maybe include it in your post to clarify. Did you look at one of the various guides/tutorials for it?

Answer (score 10):

Okay, I finally got PHP + Nginx working on Windows 10 bash.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
```

**/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Installed php-fpm using `apt-get install php5-cgi php5-fpm`

Edit php.ini at `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

Restarted using `service nginx restart && service php5-fpm restart`

One thing I noticed is symbolic links doesnt work. So I had to copy configuration file for virtual hosts from the sites-available to sites-enabled directory.

Comment: I got it working via tips from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/nginx-error-111-connection-refused

Comment: You've just solved this after an hour of searching for me, cheers! - Why not mark yourself as the right answer?

Comment: Wondering how much this would change using php7.0. Running into the same issue as the above on WSL.

Comment: Great! it works on php 7.0 on my machine. thank you.

Comment: how can i upgrade php 7.0 on WSL? also, what does it mean when NGINX is described as a "reverse proxy" server?

Comment: A reverse proxy means it takes a request, and maps it to another request handler on the same machine. Often times when you have multiple servers on one device, you can use a reverse proxy to field all requests and then pass them to the correct server